# iOS "UITemporaryLayoutHeight" constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to get the smallest size for a custom view subclass that satisfies its internal constraints.

```
let someView = SomeView()        
someView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
someView.setNeedsLayout()
someView.layoutIfNeeded()

let viewSize = someView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

println(viewSize) // PRINTS (0.0, 96.0) WHICH IS RIGHT!
```

I get the correct value but I also get a `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` warning:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff16b753190 '_UITemporaryLayoutHeight' V:[ProjectName.SomeView:0x7ff16b772210(0)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff16b75de50 UIImageView:0x7ff16b76eff0.top == ProjectName.SomeView:0x7ff16b772210.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff16b7653f0 UIImageView:0x7ff16b76eff0.bottom <= ProjectName.SomeView:0x7ff16b772210.bottomMargin>"
```

Below is my `SomeView` UIView subclass.

It just contains an 80x80 imageView pinned to the top, left and bottom margins. (I am using [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) to write constraints).

Now obviously this view will have a fixed height of 96 (80 + 8x2 for margins) but theoretically it could stretch if its subviews changed size.

Any ideas? Searching google for `UITemporaryLayoutHeight` (or Width) gives 0 results...

```
class SomeView: UIView {

    let imageView = UIImageView()

    var constraintsSet = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {

        if(!constraintsSet) {

            imageView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Top)
            imageView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Left)
            imageView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Bottom, relation: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual)
            imageView.autoSetDimension(.Width, toSize: 80.0)
            imageView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 80.0)

            constraintsSet = true
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This:

> It just contains an 80x80 imageView pinned to the top, left and bottom margins

and this

> NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff16b753190 '_UITemporaryLayoutHeight' V:[ProjectName.SomeView:0x7ff16b772210(0)]

is the source of the problem. UIKit is at some point in the load/layout/display process using a height of 0. Since you have constraints to both top and bottom **and** imageview has its intrinsic content size, you are telling it to fit the image into zero-vertical space.

The usual way to resolve this is to set either top or bottom constraint's priority to anything less than 1000.

Comment: As a side note: I would really love to hear explanation from Apple about these _UITemporaryLayoutHeight and similar stuff that popup in the console.

Comment: Someone please ask at WWDC labs and report back. My guess: they put the constraint there to make the OS explicitly call out your view for not being happy about being shrunk to 0 size.

Comment: Voted this because it worked after I changed parent view height-constraints' priority to medium/500.

Answer (score 49):

I've noticed this happening to me if I call `layoutIfNeeded` on a view before its parent has been laid out. I would bet if you removed `someView.layoutIfNeeded()` you wouldn't see that error anymore. You could probably also get rid of `someView.setNeedsLayout()` and replace it with `someView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()`. `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` shouldn't require the views be actually laid out, it just needs the constraints to be configured properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Indeed, calling `layoutIfNeeded()` before the view is added to its parent is the cause. And replacing `layoutIfNeeded()` by `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` removes the warning from Xcode.

Comment: Saved me a lot of headache, thanks for this answer!

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this for hours

Answer (score 10):

I had this warning when the view doesn't have a `superview` and `layoutIfNeeded` is called.
My solution was to call `layoutIfNeeded` after the view is added on a `superview`. I hope this helps:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Why did somebody down voted this? This works totally for me. I'd like to know why though.

Comment: This worked for me. layoutIfNeeded was causing problems on a view with no superview.

Answer (score 4):

The place where you are adding the constraints seems to be the source of your problem.

Also, you need to set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` to the `imageView`

Try adding the constraints when you add the image as subview.

Something like this should work:

```
class SomeView: UIView {

    let imageView = UIImageView()

    var constraintsSet = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        addSubview(imageView)

        // Don't forget this
        imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        imageView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Top)
        imageView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Left)
        imageView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Bottom, relation: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual)
        imageView.autoSetDimension(.Width, toSize: 80.0)
        imageView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 80.0)
    }
}
```

Hope this work. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm pretty sure that PureLayout automatically sets setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, so that's why I left it out.. Regarding the place where I add constraints, I have read in many places (including Apple docs) that constraints should be added in the updateConstraints() method. I tried moving them in the init() method and I get a different warning:

`"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9662fb5be0 V:[ProjectName.SomeView:0x7f9662fb7d50(0)]>"`

Height  still gets set to 0 but without the `UITemporaryLayoutHeight` name

Answer (score 2):

My case is completely different.  In my code, I am adding arranged subviews to a UIStackView.  I am also adding explicit height constraints to the subviews:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonStack: UIStackView!
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
...
        for i in 0 ..< entry.names.count {
            let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
            buttons.append(button)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
            buttonStack.insertArrangedSubview(button, at: buttonStack.arrangedSubviews.count-1)
        }
```

This will lead to UITemporaryLayoutHeight constraints that conflict with the constraint I added above.  To fix the problem, I first added to the UIStackView, updated the UIStackView constraints, and *then* added my own constraints to my subviews.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonStack: UIStackView!
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
...
        for i in 0 ..< entry.names.count {
            let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
            buttons.append(button)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            buttonStack.insertArrangedSubview(button, at: buttonStack.arrangedSubviews.count-1)
        }
        buttonStack.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        for button in buttons {
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experiment and testing it cause of "**view.layoutIfNeeded()**".
Because the view construct without its superview. So, in order to silent this warning you need to run your "**view.layoutIfNeeded()**" inside "**DispatchQueue.main.async**"

example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.pageControl.layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = self.pageControl.frame.size
    self.topPageControlConstraint.constant = 16
    self.trailingPageControlConstraint.constant = 16
}
```